# Using JQuery to open close menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

ok so I have this script that controls an open/close of menu ....

of the three major functions (seen below) the first two work well in that the button-toggle changes its class (to an X) "active" which makes it an X.

However the fourth (commented out )function doesn't work... This was designed so that when you click on the body or anywhere other than the menu when it is open , it will close.  please can someone help me to rewrite the last function so that it works.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $navToggle = $('.nav-toggle');
    $(".navbtn").click(function () {
        if($navToggle.hasClass('active')){
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('collapse');
            $navToggle.removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
        else{
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('expand');
            $navToggle.addClass('active');
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    });
$(".navbtn").hover(function () {
    $('.nav-toggle').addClass('hover');
},function(){
    $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('hover');
});


/*$('body').on('click', function(e){
 if( !$(this).closest('#menu, .navbtn, .nav-toggle').length) {
    $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('collapse');
    $navToggle.removeClass('active');
        e.stopPropagation();        
    }; 
});*/
});
```

I have provided a JSFiddle below (The menu is set to full colapse on startup not open as in the demo fyi)

http://jsfiddle.net/greggy_coding/ppX53/66/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `e.target` instead of `this`, as `this` refers body and not current clicked element.

---

**[event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/)**

> The DOM element that initiated the event.

---

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('#menu, .navbtn, .nav-toggle').length) {
        $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('collapse');
        $navToggle.removeClass('active');
        e.stopPropagation();
    };
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppX53/74/)**

Comment: this seems to work... ! forgive my disbelief even with my own eyes I have been trying to sort it out for days now so thanks very much !

Comment: it is very strange but now the menu css styling doesn't appear directly because of the code ? any ideas ?

Comment: I did not get you. Can you elaborate?

Comment: i think it is because the function for multipushmenu(init) needs to be in place perhaps , the function still works but the menu is just styled text and not with boxes etc

Comment: Can you tell me the steps to reproduce it in the fiddle? Styling seems to be fine.

Comment: yes basically the first two lines if they are taken out then it works .... 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu();
});

Comment: maybe it is some sort of conflict withthe multipushmenu.js    ... either way it works so i guess that is ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified javascript that would work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu();
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    var $navToggle = $('.nav-toggle');
    $(".navbtn").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if($navToggle.hasClass('active')){
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('collapse');
            $navToggle.removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
        else{
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('expand');
            $navToggle.addClass('active');
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    });

    $(".navbtn").hover(function () {
        $('.nav-toggle').addClass('hover');
    },function(){
         $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('hover');
    });

    $('#menu').on('click', function(e) {
         e.stopPropagation();
    });


    $('body').on('click', function(e){
        $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('collapse');
        $navToggle.removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Here is the forked working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ytnLyqrv/1/